# Nraas Master Controller causes Sims 3 to close automatically

Tags: the-sims-3

I have Sims 3 Ambitions expansion pack and want to install the Master Controller.
https://www.nraas.net/community/MasterController

However, the second I start the game, the entire window will close by itself on the loading screen. If I remove the mod from the mods file, it stops happening. How can I fix this problem?

I have one other mod, which skips the intro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My most likely guess is that the game needs to be updated to the latest patch, use the superpatch at https://simsvip.com/2014/01/24/sims-3-game-update-1-67-12414/ to update.